# How to find local max and min point with e

Tags: calculus

I have this question:

Find any stationary point of the graphs of:

y = 2 - e^x

and determine whether they are maxima or minima.

So I differentiated the function:

y' = -e^x = 0

isn't there no solution?

So how would you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right, there is no solution, and so there are no stationary points.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential is nowhere zero, and so there are no stationary points - hence no max and min. There's nothing else to do.

Answer (score 0):

$e^x$ is an increasing function with no stationary point, its range is $(0,\infty)$.

Similarly $2-e^x$ has no stationary point, it has no maximum or minimum, from the above, its range is $(-\infty, 2)$. The supremum is $2$ but it is not a maximum.